# How i can create new issue at GNU Bison Project?

Tags: bison, issue-tracking

How i can create new issue at GNU Bison Project?

I already investigete https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/, and
http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/bison/

on http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/bison/ - last news about Bison 3.8.1 - but on the Internet a long time ago there is version 3.8.2. Is this site alive ?? I am tried to register on savannah.gnu.org, but even have not receive confimation email...

also i found https://github.com/akimd/bison - it's official repo?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only option is to use the mailing list: https://savannah.gnu.org/mail/?group=bison At least I don't see any forum, discord or github. The project seems to be managed in the old style.

Comment: I'm not sure if the GitHub repo you've provided is official. It looks pretty popular but may be a mirror. In any case, the `README.md` direct you to the mailing list if you have a bug report.